# Importing MySQL tables from other database in live site with mysqldump can cause trouble?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysqldump

Scenario: I want to replicate MySQL tables from one database to other database.

Possible best solution: May be to use MySQL Replication feature.
Current solution on what I'm working as workaround (mysqldump) because can't spend time to learn about Replication in current deadline.

So currently I'm using command like this:

```
mysqldump -u user1 -ppassword1 --single-transaction SourceDb TblName | mysql -u user2 -ppassword2 DestinationDB
```

Based on some tests, it seems to be working fine.
While running above command, I run *ab* command with 1000 requests on destination site and tried accessing the site from browser also.

My concern is for destination live site on which we are importing data with whole table (which will internally drop existing table and create new one with new data).

Can I be sure that live site won't break while this process or is there any risk factor?
If yes then can that be resolved?

Comment: Asked this question to stackoverflow but this place seems more suitable so closing this question there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369038/importing-mysql-tables-from-other-database-in-live-site-with-mysqldump-can-cause

Comment: are you sure you don't have `"-h"` option in your `mysqldump...` command?

Comment: Yes, because I'm connecting to localhost (default) and both databases are on same MySQL server for now.

Comment: If they're on same "server" then  replication is not the solution.
Things other than that you can try using triggers (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) on main table targetting the destination table.

Comment: Yeah, trigger was the first thought came in my mind but one of our team mate suggested that trigger would take quite a load on MySQL server if we want to replicate the changes to many (10 or more) databases and they are difficult to manage also.

Comment: Why don't you read from the source table only? I don't really able to make sense of the usage here...

Comment: You're right, from current scenario it's not making sense but the idea is to customize each site having different database and we will replicate only specific data from one site.

That's also the reason we avoided to choose MySQL Replication because none of us in our team found that we can replicate specific/filtered records with that feature.

For that scenario, mysqldump is also not proper solution and that's why we are not going with mysqldump forever but it's just for short time, we are analysing this approach (might be quick and dirty approach).

Answer (score 1):

If they are on the same server, I'd do the table 'copy/replicate' this way:

```
CREATE TABLE detinationDB.new_table like sourceDB.TblName;
INSERT INTO detinationDB.new_table SELECT * FROM sourceDB.TblName;
RENAME TABLE detinationDB.TblName TO detinationDB.DropMe, detinationDB.new_table TO detinationDB.TblName;
DROP TABLE detinationDB.DropMe;
```

This way, you avoid dropping the old table before making sure the new table is there.

This is good if you intend to keep booth DBs on the same server.

Comment: I think, that's almost like mysqldump but mysqldump can manage transaction for source table and it seems that it's not breaking destination table (not sure about all scenarios and also not sure how good it could be with transactions) but with your solution, we need to manage transactions explicitly

Comment: The main statement here is `INSERT INTO.... SELECT FROM`, which by itself is one transaction. This is especially true if your table is InnoDB. I didn't get your concerns about transactions here